# How print AJAX data?

Tags: javascript

Thanks to people from stackoverflow, they helped me to realize my functional with Ajax, but now I have another problem. Below is code:

```
if(isset($_POST['site'])){
if($_POST['site'] == NULL)
{
echo "Field cannot be empty";
return;
}

//here we check site validation on server side 
if (!preg_match("~^(?:(?:https?|ftp|telnet)://(?:[a-z0-9_-]{1,32}".
"(?::[a-z0-9_-]{1,32})?@)?)?(?:(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,128}\.)+(?:com|net|".
"org|mil|edu|arpa|gov|biz|info|aero|inc|name|[a-z]{2})|(?!0)(?:(?".
"!0[^.]|255)[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?!0|255)[0-9]{1,3})(?:/[a-z0-9.,_@%&".
"?+=\~/-]*)?(?:#[^ '\"&<>]*)?$~i", $_POST['site']))
{
echo "<br/>";
echo "<div id='err'>Oooops!!! Wrong site name</div>";
return;
} 

$homepage = file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['site']);
preg_match('%<meta.*name="keywords".*content="(.*)"\s+/>%U', $homepage, $regs);



if(count($regs))
 {
$myString = implode( '', $regs );  
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "<div id='test'>Keywords:</div>";
 print_r( "<div id='test2'>$myString</div>");
}
else
{
echo "<br/>";
echo "<div id='test'>There is no keywords</div>";
}
}


?>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#payment').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = $('input[name=site]').val();

       $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
            url: 'test.php',
            //data: $(this).serialize(),
            data: x,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                 $('#metaTags').text(data)
            },
             error:   function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status);} 

        });
    });
});
</script>


</head>     

<div>
<form id="payment"    method="post" name="forma1">
    <label for=name>ENTER www.bbc.com:</label>
    <input id="name" type=text placeholder="Write here..."         name="site">
    <input type="submit" value="START" name="searchbutton" id="sb">
</form>

<div id="metaTags"></div>

</div>  


</html>
```

Everything is ok, but the output you can see here:
http://tsite.500mb.net/test.php
for testing type for example: www.bbc.com and you'll see the output result
I need that the otput will  only meta tags, without source code. How to do it?
I tried next idea:

```
var x = $('input[name=site]').val();
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
            url: 'test.php',
    data: x,
```

where data = x, and x - value from input textbox, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to return; before you <html> starts.

Comment: You mean RETURN after if..else on php code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) function, here is a quick and dirty sample you can take further.

#### php

```
<?

if (isset($_POST['site'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['site'])) {

        echo "<div>Field cannot be empty</div>";

    } else {

        //here we check site validation on server side
        if (!preg_match("~^(?:(?:https?|ftp|telnet)://(?:[a-z0-9_-]{1,32}" .
                "(?::[a-z0-9_-]{1,32})?@)?)?(?:(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,128}\.)+(?:com|net|" .
                "org|mil|edu|arpa|gov|biz|info|aero|inc|name|[a-z]{2})|(?!0)(?:(?" .
                "!0[^.]|255)[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?!0|255)[0-9]{1,3})(?:/[a-z0-9.,_@%&" .
                "?+=\~/-]*)?(?:#[^ '\"&<>]*)?$~i", $_POST['site'])) {

            echo "<div id='err'>Oooops!!! Wrong site name</div>";
        }

        $metatags = get_meta_tags("http://" . $_POST['site']);

        /* List all meta tags
        echo "<pre>".print_r($metatags, true)."</pre>";
        */

        if (count($metatags)) {
            foreach ($metatags as $tag => $value) {
                echo "<div class=\"result\"><strong>$tag:</strong> $value</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div id='test'>There is no keywords</div>";
        }
    }

    return;
}

?>
```

#### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#payment').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var x = $('input[name=site]').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {site: x},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#metaTags').html(response)
                    },
                    error:   function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .result {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form id="payment" method="post" name="forma1">
            <label for="name">ENTER www.bbc.com:</label>
            <input id="name" type=text placeholder="Write here..." name="site">
            <input type="submit" value="START" name="searchbutton" id="sb">
        </form>

        <div id="metaTags"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, my url pointed to another file. Updated my answer now. Should be url: 'test.php', not url: 'testing.php'. That's what causing the 404 on your end.

Comment: Wow, nice, now I see full list of tags and etc, and how to print only for example Description tags or keywords? Is it possible in php?

Comment: I tried next variant:
       $all_meta['keywords'];
  $keywords = strtolower($all_meta['keywords']);
        $metatags = get_meta_tags("http://" . $_POST['site']);

        /* List all meta tags
        echo "<pre>".print_r($metatags, true)."</pre>";
        */

        if (count($metatags)) {
            foreach ($metatags as $keyword => $value) {
                echo "<div class=\"result\"><strong>$keyword:         </strong> $value</div>";
            }
        }

Comment: If you uncomment "List all meta tags" where it prints out the result, you will see it's a array of all meta tags found. then you can use `echo $metatags['description'];` or whatever meta tag you want. For keywords, use `echo "<strong>Keywords:</strong> ".$metatags['keywords'];` instead of the foreach loop. You might want to use `isset($metatags['keywords'])` instead of the `count($metatags)` check.

Comment: Yes thanks, it works, super. I have one problem again. I tested this script on localhost and it worked, but now I try test it on host and it doesn't work. When I try search all meta keywords, I receive message, that there are 0 keywords(but when I tested on localhost, it was ok)...Hmm...Any ideas guys?

Comment: Then you need to debug. For starters, uncomment `echo "<pre>".print_r($metatags, true)."</pre>";` to see if you get any results from get_meta_tags().

Comment: No, I used another variant, like this $value = $_POST['web_url']; $tag = get_meta_tags("http://".$value);

        if(count($tag['keywords']) == 0)
        {
            echo "<div id='no_keywords'>Keywords not found</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div id='title'>List of keywords:</div>";
            echo "<br/>";
            print_r($tag['keywords']);
        }

Comment: What can be cause of problem? May be hosting? Or no?

Comment: Very strange situation, because on localhost is OK, but on hosting - ELSE ..print_r($tag['keywords']); doesn't work...hmmm..Guys, how to fix it?